# How do I make the login window appear in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'd like to make the login window appear in phpmyadmin.
I have a MAMP environment (MacOS) and I note the access to phpmyadmin is without the window login.

Thank you in advance
Andrea

I have tried to modify the config file **confg.inc.php** in the directory
**/Application/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin**

I have apported  this modify:
I have replaced the row **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';**
with **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';**
After this modify i don't see any change.

Can you help me ?

Thank you
Andrea